# How to obtain only one specific NEXTVAL result in an Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my  stored proc, I run a query like soi :

```
SELECT NETWORKOWNER.BUS_SEQ.NEXTVAL@LEGACYSMITH.WORLD 
FROM TBLDECIDERCONTRACT@LEGACYSMITH.WORLD
WHER PROVID = 28938
```

How would obtaon only *one* NEXTVAL result?

Answer (score 5):

Using `dual`:

```
SELECT NETWORKOWNER.BUS_SEQ.NEXTVAL@LEGACYSMITH.WORLD FROM dual
```

Answer (score 4):

Or more generally: make sure your FROM and WHERE clauses result in just one row found - then NEXTVAL will be executed just once.

In addition, you can always get just a single NEXTVAL execution by invoking it natively in PL/SQL, as in:

```
DECLARE
   l_seq INTEGER;
BEGIN
   l_seq := my_sequence.NEXTVAL;
END;
```